# webpack and terser leaks source filenames in minified output

Tags: javascript, webpack, terser

Is there a way to prevent source filenames from propagating to webpack output, when using Terser to minify?

### Example

In the `.js` output file produced by my minified production React app build, I'm still seeing un-mangled source filenames in the output.

Example excerpt:

```
[...]
({"../js/dashboard/lib/MyApiClient.js":function(e,t,n){"use
strict";n.r(t),n.d(t,"default",function(){return c});var
o=n("../node_modules/axios/index.js"),r=n.n(o),
s=n("../node_modules/@sentry/browser/esm/index.js");
[...]
```

You can see a few things here:

- My proprietary code has some sort of module called `MyApiClient.js`
- We're using `axios` and `Sentry`

### Webpack config

Here's the relevant portion of our production webpack config:

```
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        extractComments: false,
        terserOptions: {
          output: {
            comments: false,
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
```

### The problem

My concern is that this is **leaking information about the internal structure** of our app, and I haven't quite found the right place in the stack (webpack options? terser options?) to prevent it.

Though the examples above are benign, and of course no amount of mangling makes the code impervious to reverse engineering the functionality, I don't want to make it *too* easy for others to understand how the app is built & what features it may be hiding.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell, the way webpack bundles your modules is making `require` work in the browser by searching in an object map of filenames to the bundled code associated with those filenames. In other words, this is kind of how webpack works, and you'd be hard-pressed to find a way around it. If you really care, you could run something that finds all strings in `require` calls and mangles all instances of them in the code after building.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to webpack's [`optimization.namedModules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationnamedmodules) option which should be **false** by default, maybe it is enabled in your config.

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    namedModules: false
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the problem. Specifically, I thought I had `mode: "production"` configured, which should have disabled this in the prod build; but for unrelated reasons that setting was broken.

Answer (score 0):

Consider also turning `sourceMap: false` on production, since that is the feature that maps the code to file names.

Comment: He's talking about the filenames being shown within the generated `.js` file, NOT source maps. This is definitely an issue for him too, but it doesn't relate to the question he asked.